# Why does the same code using struct.unpack with a bytearray raise an exception in Python 2.7.3 but not in 2.7.5?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, unpack

I wrote an application that uses `struct.unpack` on byte arrays. Running it on my machine using Python 2.7.5 it works well:

```
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> struct.unpack("<Q", data)   
(7,)
```

However, I tried to use it with Python version 2.7.3 I got an exception:

> error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

I need to explicitly cast the bytearray to string before unpacking it. Is this related to the Python version change? the [struct manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) says nothing about this. I would like to avoid doing all the casting, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, this is related to Python version. Apparently `struct.unpack` was fixed or extended after version 2.7.3.

If your script must work with both version 2.7.5 and 2.7.3 and you have found a way to make it run on both versions (by casting to string) then you can put your workaround code along with the call to `struct.unpack` into a function and call this function instead of doing directly the casting and calling of `struct.unpack` wherever you need to do it. This way your code will stay elegant, short and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can wrap bytearray object with bytes:

```
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> struct.unpack("<Q", bytes(data))   
(7,)
```

It works on Python3 too.